# Prove that all cycles of $S_n$ are generated by these transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Prove that all cycles of $S_n$ are generated by the transpositions $\{(ij) \mid 1 \leq i < j \leq n\}$ (do not assume any other set of transpositions generate the cycles of $S_n$).

So if we have a cycle $(x_1 x_2 x_3 \ldots x_n)$ then we have to show that the transpositions as stated above: $(x_1 x_n)(x_1 x_{n-1}) \ldots (x_1 x_2) (x_2 x_n) (x_2 x_{n-1}) \ldots (x_2 x_3) \ldots (x_{n- 1} x_n)$ generate this cycle.

So if $k \neq 1 \neq n$, then $x_k$ is first ocurred in the cycle $(x_k, x_{k+1})$. So $x_k$ goes to $x_{k+1}$. Then $x_{k+1}$ goes to $x_{k-1}$ since the next cycle where $x_{k+1}$ is seen is in $(x_{k-1} x_{k+1}$), and then $x_{k-1}$ goes to $x_{k-2}$ (in $(x_{k-2} x_{k-1})$), etc. until finally $(x_2 x_3)$. Then $(x_1 x_2)$ and lastly $(x_1 x_3)$. So $x_k$ goes to $x_3$, which doesn't really help my case here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The symmetric group is even generated by all [adjacent transpositions](http://planetmath.org/symmetricgroupisgeneratedbyadjacenttranspositions), hence in particular by all transpositions $(ij)$ with $i<j$. Furthermore, in the [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf) of Keith Conrad you can find all proofs for many different sets of generators of $S_n$, in particular, Theorem $2.1$. The proof is just this: every $n$-cycle is the product of transpositions as follows:
$$
(x_1\,x_2\,\ldots x_n)=(x_1\,x_2)(x_2\,x_3)\cdots (x_{n-1}\,x_n).
$$
For, say, $(13526)$ this gives $(13)(35)(52)(26)$. Hence these transpositions (and so all transpositions) generate all cycles.

Comment: Sorry, I left out a part of the question. It says I am not allowed to use the fact that the symmetric group is generated by all adjacent transpositions

Comment: But the proof given there proves that all transpositions you list generate $S_n$. So it proves your question.

Comment: But using the result of that proof would mean I am using a result I am not allowed to

Comment: In Keith Conrad's notes, the transpositions he gives is $(i_1 i_2)(i_2 i_3)...(i_{k-1} i_k)$ which is not the transpositions in my problem. His transpositions is missing many that mine has (such as $(i_1 i_3)$ for example).

Comment: You can just add them. If, say, $x,y$ generate a group, then also $x,y,z$ may generate the group. The same with vector spaces. If $e_1, e_2$ generated$\mathbb{R}^2$, then also, say, $e_1,e_2,e_3=e_1-e_2$ generate it.

Comment: Actually, the problem after this one is: "Use the result from the previous problem that the transpositions $(12), (23), ... , (n-1 n)$ are enough generate $S_n$." I think that is why I was not supposed to use the result for this problem, because I am supposed to use it to solve the next one

Comment: That is exactly what Keith Conrad is doing (Theorem $2.1$, Theorem $2.3$ and so on) - read his notes, they contain all the information you need.

Comment: But even if Thereom $2.1$ is the one I want, he states that "every cycle is a product of transpositions" but he doesn't prove this. He uses the result that every cycle is a product of transpositions to say that the products of transpositions give us all cycles, which seems like circular reasoning to me

Answer (score 2):

Hint: In the following, transpositions act on group from right to left.

$(x_1x_2)$=$(x_1x_2)$

$(x_1x_2x_3)$=$(x_1x_3)(x_1x_2)$

$(x_1x_2x_3x_4)$=$(x_1x_4)(x_1x_3)(x_1x_2)$

See the pattern? The proof is simple induction. With a cycle of $n$ elements we can just as easily extend to $n+1$ elements by adding a transposition switching the first and the last.