# How many unique ways are there perform $n$ swaps on set of elements $S$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider the set $S = [a, b, c]$,

If we ask:

> How many ways are there to perform a single swap ($n = 1$) on $S$?

The possibilities are:

- swap elements 1 and 2
- swap elements 1 and 3
- swap elements 2 and 3

...and can be generalized as:
$${|S| \choose 2} = {3 \choose 2} = 3$$

When we ask:

> How many ways are there to perform exactly 2 swaps ($n = 2$) on $S$?

The naive answer is that there are the following possibilities:

- case #1 -  swap elements 1 and 2, then 1 and 3
- case #2 -  swap elements 1 and 2, then 2 and 3
- case #3 -  swap elements 1 and 3, then 2 and 3

However, if we example case #1 and case #3 more carefully, we see that they both result in the same transformed set:
$$S = [c,a,b]$$

Which brings me to my question:

**What is the correct formula which expresses the number of unique swaps that be performed on a set of length $|S|$ and swap count n?** *(It quickly becomes very difficult to calculate by hand for higher values of |S| and n).*

*Motivation: This problem is a subset of a larger problem I am working on. Finding a closed-form solution for the problem described above will allow me to calculate $|G|$ in an application of [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). I'm a Engineer by profession (and new to the site), so any advice on math formatting/conventions is appreciated.*

Comment: This seems a *lot* like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the group that you're after the order of?

Comment: @user3482749 I'm after the cardinality of the set with the characteristics described above. If I write a computer program to generate all ((|S| choose 2) choose n) combinations, then eliminate the equivalent elements, I get the correct solutions for the parent problem.

I need a closed-form solution for this problem purely for optimization purposes.

Comment: This question and answers may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448495/prove-that-all-cycles-of-s-n-are-generated-by-these-transpositions (since for a given size of $S$ there is an $n$ such that $n$ transpositions generate all permutations.

Comment: OEIS: [A094638](https://oeis.org/A094638)

Comment: @DanielMathias That is indeed the sequence I am after. Can you help me understand how to generate these numbers? I'm a little unfamiliar with both the mathematical concepts and formatting conventions found on OEIS.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how many transpositions there are for a symmetric group with $n$ elements. The number is indeed $\left( \begin{array}{l} n \\ 2 \end{array}\right)$. See [The number of transpositions in Symmetric group is $n(n-1)/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121706/the-number-of-transpositions-in-symmetric-group-is-nn-1-2)

Comment: After reading a little bit about symmetric groups, I believe what I want to know the number of _successive_ transpositions on a symmetric group with n elements. For a single transposition, the answer is indeed (n choose 2), but what about 2 successive transpositions? 3, 4, 5 etc...?

Comment: *by _successive_ transpositions I think I mean product of n transpositions. Sorry for the misleading use of the letter _n_.

Comment: You are then talking about permutations; every permutation is the product of transpositions.

Answer (score 0):

(Excuse my poor English)

Compare a transpotion to the source group, as every moved element has a new place to stay, we can always group the transitions into several oriented rings.

For example,
Transpotion [a,c,d,b] from group [a,b,c,d],

We get 2 rings:

{a}{c->b->d}

As each length of ring need at least one swap and will decrease the total ring count by 1, when we got a transpotion of m rings from a n-sized group, we need at least (n-m) swaps.

So, the new transpotion count from a n-sized group at the Kth swap is the reversed Unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind [A094638](https://oeis.org/A094638) (Start from 0 swap):

$T(n,k)=[\mathop{}_{n-k}^{n}]$

In addition, the total transpotion count from a n-sized group at exact Kth is the even/odd sum of T(n,1~k). That's because every single swap will take a change of even/odd permutation (Even/odd is for the count of element further ahead in source group than the next element in transpotion), the result is [A087644](https://oeis.org/A087644).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).